# Using the org.json java package, how would I replace the values of certain json values, and then put them back into the main file?

Tags: java, json, org.json

I'm relatively new to Java, and I'm struggling to find any "easy to understand" documentation on how to properly use the org.json package, and I can't seem to find any function that replaces the value of a key, only adding new ones.

***By the way, sorry if this post isn't properly formatted or something, am also new to stackoverflow.***

This is the content of my JSON file:

```
{
  "gbp": [
    {
      "yen": 183.65,
      "usd": 1.28,
      "euro": 1.17
    }
  ],
  "usd": [
    {
      "yen": 144.67,
      "gbp": 0.79,
      "euro": 0.92
    }
  ],
  "euro": [
    {
      "yen": 156.96,
      "usd": 1.08,
      "gbp": 0.85
    }
  ],
  "yen": [
    {
      "euro": 0.0064,
      "usd": 0.0069,
      "gbp": 0.0054
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the code that loads the jsonContent into a string then an object:

```java
String jsonContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/rates.json")));
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonContent);
```

I then need to find the missing currency in an ArrayList named: `orderOfExchangesForConfirmRateChanges`. This is in a separate java file, so it is called with: `gui.orderOfExchangesForConfirmRateChanges`.
This is done with this code:

```java
            String requiredCurrency = null; //this is needed for later
            String[] currencies = new String[] {"usd", "gbp", "euro", "yen"};
            for(String currency : currencies){
                if(!gui.orderOfExchangesForConfirmRateChanges.toString().contains(currency)){
                    requiredCurrency = currency;
                    System.out.println("Found currency.");
                }
            }
```

Once this has completed, we call this bit of code to get the data within the json file corresponding to the
`requiredCurrency` variable:

```java
JSONArray desiredJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(requiredCurrency);
System.out.println(desiredJsonArray); // here to help me visualise things - example, if requiredCurrency = euro, output would be: [{"yen":156.96,"gbp":0.85,"usd":1.08}]
```

So hereafter, I need to change the values of "yen", "gbp", "usd", but I cannot seem to figure it out.
For example if I wanted to change the contents of the euro section of `rates.json` from:

```
{
   "euro": [
       {
      "yen": 144.67,
      "gbp": 0.79,
      "euro": 0.92
       }
  ]
}
```

to:

```
{
   "euro": [
       {
      "yen": 2000,
      "gbp": 50,
      "euro": 100
       }
  ]
}
```

And then re-insert it into the main JSONObject and rewrite the rates.json file to include these new values.

Sorry if this question is a bit all over the place.

**If anything needs to be cleared up or re-explained, let me know**

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost had it.

In your json structure, the value for each currency is an array which contains a single object. To change a value of a specific currency inside an array, you need to get the JSONObject from the array then change the value.

```
// This is from your code
JSONArray jsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("gbp");
JSONObject desiredJsonArray = jsArray.getJSONObject(0);

// This is the update part
desiredJsonArray.put("yen", 155);
desiredJsonArray.put("gbp", 1);
desiredJsonArray.put("usd", 2);
```

now, write json back to file:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("src/rates.json"), jsonObject.toString(4).getBytes());
```